# City Country State Database

Tags: database, geolocation, location

I am looking for a good City, Country State database

It does not have to be crazy detailed, something that has a good coverage of Cities and their corresponding State,Countries in the world will do it for me.

Appreciate if you can point me some links. Thanks

Comment: This information may be difficult to get all in one package. Many countries organize their locales in very different manners. Some smaller countries will not have the concept of state for example while geographically larger countries will have a hierarchy of provinces, districts etc. In brief, there is probably not a unified model that covers the world.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Although as an alternative, have you considered tapping into the Google Maps API?  It's free, and they provide good instructions to integrate your app.

Comment: @psasik: Not true. See http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity_CSV/GeoLiteCity_20091101.zip

Comment: @psasik.. At the bottom of the page I linked to, it said it had worldwide coverage. Look at the table at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

have a cities of the world CSV dataset compiled from the USGS GNIS Server (US) and US NGA GNS Server (non-US), that I have placed into the public domain. Below is a link and metadata of the layout.

Column 1: ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.
 Column 2: US FIPS 5-2 1st level administrative division code (e.g., state/province).
 Column 3: NGA GNS Feature Description (DSG) code.
 Column 4: NGA GNS Unique Feature Identifier (UFI).
 Column 5: ISO 639-1 alpha-2/3 code for language corresponding to the feature name.
 Column 6: Language script (e.g., latin, arabic, chinese, etc) corresponding to the feature name.
 Column 7: Feature name.
 Column 8: Latitude coordinate of the area centroid.
 Column 9: Longitude coordinate of the area centroid.

http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#cities

Answer (score 0):

You can use cities / states/ countries database in Mysql / SQL from here -

http://myip.ms/info/cities_sql_database/World_Cities_SQL_Mysql_Database.html