# Get States list of states according to selected country

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to retrieve names of all the states list of a particular country which is selected from a drop down menu.

I know how to retrieve the list of all countries via apple code but now i want the list of all the states.

Is there any code db or API available for that?

Comment: Right now i m not storing any data for that that's why i m asking from  where i can get that db or data???

Comment: Possible Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813256/how-to-put-all-countries-cities-states-of-the-world-into-my-database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/37n3e5izecvccy4/Country.sqlite) this sqlite file. This is a database of countries with their respective states. you can re - create a query every time the user selects a country.

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select zone_id , name from
                       zone where country_id = %d", countryID];
```

Comment: how to get list of states of a selected country

Comment: how to get list of states using country code