# Get states of a country when a country is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I have a code where it shows all countries and we can select a specific country from it. What i want now is when i select a country i want to see the list of states in that country. Can any one please help me in that ? Is there a method or API for it? Any help is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `db` for getting `countries and its states`. Just [download](http://www.mediafire.com/?bvrl7zauyacj41q) it.

Now use this db to query like this:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select zone_id , name from
                   zone where country_id = %d", countryID]; //here countryID is country code
```

**EDIT** : Get all countries with query like this:

```
NSString *queryStrAllCountries = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name from
                   countries"];
```

Get countryID from country selected with query like this:

```
 NSString *queryStrCountry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select country_id from
                   countries where name='%@'", countryName]; //provide country name selected
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348872/get-states-list-of-states-according-to-selected-country) answer which provide information as the same.

Comment: but it shows countryID not declared.

Comment: here countryID is number defined in apple standard. See DB

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implemented your solution. I assume you are using an `UITableView`.

Then the best way to do that would be to set a `UINavigationController` as your `rootViewController` (in Interface Builders main nib) and use the `UITableViewController` view as the root view of the `UINavigationController`. Then **push another `UITableViewController`** when a row of the first table is tabbed.

If you already have some information about UINavigationController this lines may help you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

If you are looking for a tutorial on UINavigationBar and UITableView have a look [here](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/18/tutorial-using-uitableview-adding-a-detail-view-in-xcode-4/). If you want to search for a tutorial yourself, search for `UITableView detail view`.